# How to make local server working after wamp installation?

Tags: wamp

I have just installed wamp and I copied all the projects inside www folder but when I browse http://localhost/project its displays error like this.

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

I also changed the php setting and extensions but not working. So can anyone suggest for me.

Thanks

Comment: If more information may be available in the error log, can you check and see?

Also, what settings have you changed from the default WAMP installation?

Comment: The error in apache error log is like this:
[Thu Jul 23 11:46:22 2009] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/project/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/

Answer (score 0):

There can be a large number of possibilities for this error. for now, check to see if your project is using any php module that is not registered in php.ini. also check ur php.ini and httpd.conf (or whatever your apache config file is) )to see if all modules are configured correctly

Answer (score 0):

I made it working. As I am using htaccss and I forgot to enable rewrite_module so it did not work. Now it works perfectly. Thanks to all of you for your answers that made me find out the solution. :)